# Why does firebase.database() throw an error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to make a simple web app that uses firebase database, but following a tutorial, I get an error trying `let database = firebase.database()`.

The error says that `firebase.database is not a function`.

I have also tried removing the variable and directly putting `firebase.database()` into wherever I need to call it, but it also results in the same error.

I have not found any other ways online to resolve this despite looking through firebase documentation.

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

My code (some details removed):

```html
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>

        <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

        <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

        <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIza***********************************",
            authDomain: "databasetest-db3.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://databasetest-db3.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "databasetest-db3",
            storageBucket: "databasetest-db3.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "9472********",
            appId: "1:947************************************",
            measurementId: "G-EZ9*******"
        };

        // Initialise Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
        let database = firebase.database()

        function writeData() {
            database.ref("User").set({
                name: document.getElementById("nameField").value,
                age: document.getElementById("ageField").value,
            })
        }
        </script>
        <h1>User Database</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="nameField">
        <input type="text" placeholder="age" id="ageField">
        <button onclick="writeData()">Submit</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

Edit: code copied and pasted instead of image

Comment: Please add code example and not an image

Comment: Sorry as I am rather new, I do not understand what you mean. Could you please rephrase? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the realtime database, then you need to add the following script to be able to use the sdk :

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

See the corresponding [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for more details, in particular why it is not sufficient to only add the Firebase core library (i.e. `firebase-app.js`).